# Mobile baseurl and change the fontsize on mobile

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have problem with mobile version of my website. On my desktop version of website i use code:

```
<base href="http://www.myexample.com">
```

on desktop its work fine, when i type in browser: myexample.com it redirect me to the: http://www.myexample.com but on mobile, its not redirect me. Why?

Second question: i have h1 title font size on desktop: 72, and on mobile version i want to have 24px. I have this code: but its not change anything:

```
.index-title h1{
font-size: 72px;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 700px), only screen and (device-width: 700px) and (device-height: 700px), only screen and (width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape), only screen and (device-width: 700px), only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
.index-title h1{
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Whats wrong? Thanks for answers, im newbie in coding.

Screens from debugging:

[debugging screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfE16.png)

[html/css screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndlqz.png)

Comment: The media query targets screens with width of `600px` and `upwards`. You want to set `max-width` instead for 600px and below.

Comment: Thanks, i change it but still dont work. Check my topic.

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
.index-title h1{
    font-size: 15px;
} }

Comment: Yjs its still dont work, i dont know why.

Comment: The `base` element doesn’t do any redirecting (at least not on its own.) _“but on mobile, its not redirect me. Why?”_ - impossible for us to tell, because you have not shown us anything that would cause an actual redirect yet, neither for desktop or mobile. If you get automatically redirected from `example.com` to `www.example.com`, then that is most likely due to your server-side setup ... the `base` element itself does not do this.

Comment: Ok so how to do this: i need on mobile when user type example.com redirect him automaticaly to www.example.com, may i do it in code, or i have to use search console prefer version?

Answer (score 0):

[`base` HTML tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) is useful for specifying the base url for relative links on your page. It isn't responsible for redirecting to a different page. The tag you may be looking for is [`meta` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta).

Also, redirecting the client to `www.` is better handled as a rule in your webserver configuration.

The media query targets screens with width of `600px` and `upwards`. You want to set `max-width` instead for `600px` and below.

Your sample media query is just fine. See it applied in the markup sample below:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 700px), 
only screen and (device-width: 700px) and (device-height: 700px), 
only screen and (width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape), 
only screen and (device-width: 700px), 
only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
.index-title h1{
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="index-title">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I copy this code and its not working.. i dont know why, because i think its good..  -> this could cause problems? -> @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
 .container {
     width: 960px;
 }
}

Comment: No, that doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: So is there any way how to debug why its dont work? Second question: how to do, when user type example.com on mobile, auto redirect to www.example.com, thanks :)

Comment: Auto-redirection to `www.<domain>` is dependent on your server. You can readily find examples for .htaccess directives if you're using Apache to serve your request or `nginx.conf` directives if using Nginx to serve your application

Comment: Do you have this application live on a shareable URL? You may have more specific CSS selectors in your stylesheet overriding the media query. So inspect the tag in your browser's developer console to see all selectors that target it and which one does apply the `font-size`.

Comment: Yes its live: www.minecraftserver.sk

Comment: You're serving your application using Apache web server. Read up [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04#enable-htaccess-files) to see how to configure your .htaccess file to redirect non-www to www urls. You can use [Devtools device mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/) to debug your media queries. In any case, the media queries are good for me.

Comment: I edit my first topic, i add screens from html/css file and from debugging, in css/html file i have .index-title h1 and in debugging its not showing h1, thats the problem, because when i write h1 in debugging its work fine.

Comment: Your debugging screen show the target selector to be `.index-title`. Why are you writing an `h1` in the snapshot when that's not there is code. `.index-title h1` has a higher specificity than `.index-title`. [Learn about specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).